# Drools fetch same type of object from session

Tags: java, drools

I have Simple Rule in which i have insert two String type of variable in Session. now i need to fetch variables.

Code For same:

```
rule "Header Account Null Check"
    dialect "java"
    ruleflow-group "TB:Header Account Null Check"
    when
        cAccount : AccountPair( headerAccount == null )     
    then
        String error=new String();
        String validateMsg=new String();
        error="2528";
        validationMsg="Header Account must not be null"
        modify( cAccount ) {
                setErrorCode( "2528" )
        }
        insert(error);
        insert(validateMsg);
        System.out.println("Header Account null check called");
end

query "fetch validation variables"
    #conditions
    s:String();
end
```

Java Code:

```
Collection<Object> myfacts = kSession.getObjects( new ClassObjectFilter(String.class) );
```

After checking in **myfacts i got two values.**

Now the problem is there are two variables with String.class Type, I need to know which value is for **error** and which value is for **validationMsg** so that we will perform next task.

Same with Input also if we add two String variable from Session now i need to add condition on those variable. so same problem also occur for same.till now we resolved input variable problem by declaring variable as a **Global Variable**. I also need to change this strategy because its not a good decision for declaring global variable.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be pretty obvious: if you have several String objects you cannot distinguish unless their values have certain characteristics. (In your case, the error string is numeric and the other one not.) But basing an app on this is not recommended.

So you must attach an identification to the String value. For this, you can create an object containing a `String name` and a `String value`. And your RHS becomes:

```
  insert( new Result( "error", "2528" ) );
  insert( new Result( "message", "Header Account must not be null" ) );
  modify( cAccount ) {
      setErrorCode( "2528" )
  }
  System.out.println("Header Account null check called");
```

You can use the same principle for multiple inputs.

Comment: Thanks, I know this approach, scenario is we have large system with JRule, we are converting into Drools, JRule has a facility to set Input and Output parameter. i need above facility because we don't want to change the code from java prospectively.

Comment: Well, if you know all that: what's the point in asking this question?

Comment: because want to know if  any way is exist for not creating wrapper class but am able to get variables value and able to identify value of which variable.

Comment: With *variables* you know which is which, because they have a name or (at least) an address. With facts, you don't. - BTW, storing validation results in the validated fact is another option (but you know that, too - see the modify).